# How do I make a RecursiveDirectoryIterator exclude hidden folders

Tags: php

I have a recursiveDirectoryIterator like this:

```
$theme_iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($theme_folder_path)
);
foreach ($theme_iterator as $file_object) {
   // Stuff
}
```

The problem is that it iterates into the .svn hidden folders. How can I prevent this?

Edit:

I can't just add something like this in the foreach because the files from the hidden folder are allready in the array at that point and they are not all hidden.

```
if (strpos($file_object, ".") ===0) {
    continue;
}
```

Comment: something like `if ($file_object == '.svn') { continue; }`?

Comment: That doesn't work because there are files in the hidden folder that are already in the array at that point and they are not hidden.

Comment: Use `if (strpos($file_object, ".") ===0) { //do not add it to the array }`

Comment: See my updated answer, hope it will help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<?php
class RecursiveDotFilterIterator extends  RecursiveFilterIterator
{
    public function accept()
    {
        return '.' !== substr($this->current()->getFilename(), 0, 1);
    }
}

$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new RecursiveDotFilterIterator(
        new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.')
    )
);
foreach ($iterator as $x) {
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Set `flag` `RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS` to exlude files:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($theme_folder_path);

$iterator->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
    $theme_iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
       $iterator
);
```

Comment: Update answer, chek. THis will exlude it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach using `RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator`:

```
<?php

function iterate(string $path): object {
   function filter(object $info): bool {
      if ($info->isFile()) {
         return true;
      }
      return $info->getFilename()[0] !== '.';
   }
   $RDI = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path);
   $RCFI = new RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator($RDI, 'filter');
   return new RecursiveIteratorIterator($RCFI);
}

foreach (iterate('.') as $info) {
   echo $info->getPathname(), "\n";
}
```

https://php.net/class.recursivecallbackfilteriterator

Answer (score -1):

If your want to do it in a single line :

```
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path_directory, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
```