# Showing files with RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS

Tags: php

I am expecting a result such as:

```
/path/to/files/test.png
/path/to/files/folder1/test.png
/path/to/files/folder2/test.png
```

Instead I am getting:

```
/path/to/files/.hidden_folder1/test.png
/path/to/files/test.png
/path/to/files/folder1/test.png
/path/to/files/folder2/test.png
```

I do not wish subdirectories with dot to show up:

My code is below:

```
$ufo = '/path/to/files/';
$Directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($ufo,RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($Directory);
$Regex = new RegexIterator($Iterator, '/^.+(.png)$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

foreach($Regex as $name => $Regex){
    echo $name.'<br>';
}
```

It seems as if ::SKIP_DOTS is not working.

I have also tried:

```
$ufo = '/path/to/files/';
$Directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($ufo);
$Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($Directory,RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$Regex = new RegexIterator($Iterator, '/^.+(.png)$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

foreach($Regex as $name => $Regex){
    echo $name.'<br>';
}
```

The above code returns:

```
/path/to/files/folder1/test.png
/path/to/files/folder2/test.png
```

This removes the .test_folder subdirectory but also removes the current directory.

I have tried searching countless examples but can not figure out the correct formatting to return files recursively including the current path while excluding directories starting with .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I make a RecursiveDirectoryIterator exclude hidden folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889625/how-do-i-make-a-recursivedirectoryiterator-exclude-hidden-folders)

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for - ty

Comment: BTW - from [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.filesystemiterator.php#filesystemiterator.constants.skip-dots) *SKIP_DOTS - Skips dot files (. and ..).*

Answer (score 0):

Use `setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS)` method. Try this:

```
$ufo = '/path/to/files/';
$Directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($ufo);
$Directory->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$Iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($Directory);
$Regex = new RegexIterator($Iterator, '/^.+(.png)$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);

foreach($Regex as $name => $Regex){
    echo $name.'<br>';
}
```

Similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889625/how-do-i-make-a-recursivedirectoryiterator-exclude-hidden-folders).