# Ubuntu PHP CLI is it possible to bypass hidden (dot) directories when using directoryiterator

Tags: php, ubuntu, recursion, command-line-interface

Recursively iterating thru directories fails when a hidden (dot) directory is encountered.

```
$dir  = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($startDirectory, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir, RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);

foreach ($files as $file) {
```

Fails if $dir is a hidden file e.g. .config. Is there any way to bypass hidden files

Comment: Maybe try `RecursiveIteratorIterator::CATCH_GET_CHILD`

Comment: [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26889865/7644018)